# Why Hangfire server shuts down?

Tags: hangfire

I have a .net 5 application that uses Hangfire.
The problem is that as soon as the application completes it's startup, the hangfire server shuts down. If I place a breakpoint on the last line of `Startup.cs`, the hangfire server is alive.
There are no errors logged.

What might be the cause of this?

Below is the code used for adding Hangfire.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

 services.AddHangfire(config =>
            {
                config.UseSqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireDefaultConnection"), new SqlServer.SqlServerStorageOptions
                {
                    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                    DisableGlobalLocks = true,
                    SchemaName = "dbo.WR_Hangfire",
                });
            });
....

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
...
 app.UseHangfireServer();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `app.UseHangfireServer();` is deprecated and that was the problem. Solved by registering the server with `services.UseHangfireServer()`.